# android, how to avoid the flick when replace fragment with FragmentTransaction after did the popStack first

Tags: android-fragments, fragment-backstack

when adding fragments in the activity, it is done by `replace(R.id.fragment_container, theFragment, backStackTag)`.

the use case is to limit the FragmentTransaction in the backstack, i.e.

`[a]->[b]-[c]->[d]->[e]`, if adding one more `[f]`, it should pop `[e]` first so the result would be:

`[a]->[b]-[c]->[d]->[f]`

and the code: does `supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()` first to pop the `[e]`, and then do `.replace(R.id.fragment_container, theFragment, backStackTag)` to show the `[f]`.

but it will show a flick with content of `[e]` before the `[f]` is displayed.

is there a way to avoid this flickering?

```
        val theFragment = getFragment()
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > MAX_STACK_DEPTH) {
             supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
        }
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(backStackTag)
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, theFragment, backStackTag)
                        .commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` after the commit() seems does not show the flicking.
not sure if there is better solution tho.